# sql- how to arrange the data in a table without use of asc keyword?

Tags: sql-server

i have a table called customer

```
Name   Id
----- ----

vimal 34

arun  56

sasi  98
```

if i need to arrange those data in an alphabetical order we usually use query
"select * from customer where order by name asc "
similarly  to reverse we use the query
"select * from customer where order by name desc "
without use of asc and desc keyword how to arrange or reverse the data's

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? maybe some more information could get you a better solution.

Comment: I'm not the world's foremost SQL expert, but using the order by clause is the only way I can think of to do it without hurting performance. There are other SQL Server specific functions like RANK that will do the same thing but I believe there is some performance cost associated with it, and RANK will add a column to the results that you probably don't need.

Comment: What's the point?  It's like writing being told to write a novel, but not use commas.  There might be other ways, but they would be clumsy at best, and ignoring common syntax that has been there since the beginning of the language.

Comment: By definition, a SQL table has no order. The only way to provide order is by using an Order By statement.

Comment: One reason for this requirement would be to avoid dynamic SQL if the sort order can be specified by the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as
(
select Id, name, row_number() over (order by name) rn 
from customer  
)
select Id, name
from cte 
order by rn /* (Or use -rn to sort descending)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using an `ORDER BY` clause the order of the returned data is completely arbitrary; it's whatever is most convenient for the server. You can drop the `ASC` as this is the default.